# Backbone how to send url only

Tags: backbone.js

Ho to avoid the append of an id or additional parameters by backbone?

For example, if I'd like call the following url:

```
https://www.gogle.de
```

backbone sends out this url:

```
https://www.gogle.de/?_=1377848245402
```

How can I stop backbone adding an id to my url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a problem caused by Backbone. I deactivated the ajax_caching, after activating it, the ids were gone :)

```
 $.ajaxSetup ({
        // Disable caching of AJAX responses */
        cache: true
    });
```